# Laravel - can I inject a FormRequest inside a FormRequest?

Tags: forms, laravel, validation, request

I have a complex set of rules that I build dynamically but ideally I need one set of rules to be validated before I move on to the next, i.e.

I have a json object `{data: {}}`, which I want to check exists before I move on to validate fields nested in `data`, which have other nested fields etc etc.

I thought about having one `FormRequest` class, say `ApiRequest`, which could validate `data`, then another, say `UploadRequest`, which adds further rules on the basis that the `data` has already been validated.

I can do this, and it works, by injecting `ApiRequest` inside the constructor of `UploadRequest`, which allows the full set of rules to be validated in `ApiRequest`, before moving on to the next set:

```
/**
 * UploadRequest constructor.
 * @param ApiRequest $apiRequest
 */
public function __construct(ApiRequest $apiRequest) {

    // If we got here, ApiRequest passed validation, woo!

}
```

Does this seem like an anti pattern or the 'wrong' way to handle this?
I was trying to think of a request being made up of mini requests i.e. an upload request via the api is really an api request, followed by an upload request etc. But I'm not sure if I'm just trying to justify this to myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have one `ApiRequest` class that validates all mandatory parameters for all endpoints.

```
class ApiRequests extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data' => 'required',
            'data.field_1' => 'required|string',
            'data.field_2' => 'required|string'
        ];
    }

}
```

And let's say your API has an endpoint that edits user's profile. And the request made to that endpoint **must** include `first_name` and `last_name`. So a new class that extends `ApiRequest` can be made:

```
class EditUserRequest extends ClientRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            'params.first_name' => 'required',
            'params.last_name' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
}
```

That will merge all rules from `ApiRequest` with those required for `EditUserRequest`.

And then in your controller (eg. `UsersController`):

```
public function update(EditUserRequest $request) {
    .... your code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've also been doing that, but the problem is when I have a very dynamic list of rules that needs to be built, which requires access to the `data` attribute and its nested attributes (for example, I need to be able to pull out certain parts of the structure at a time to validate). I don't want to have to check if `data` etc exist every time I attempt to access it in the rules further down the line, I'd rather hit those rules knowing that data exists, because it passed the previous validation. Perhaps there's a better way for validating json data structures...

Comment: Validate the data in your controller then